# Why do you Still offer Open ID login via Claim ID when it's discontinued

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, openid, stackexchange.com

https://claimid.com/ has discontinued its service. There is no need to offer people to login with it anymore, however I can still see it listed in the Data Explorer and [Stack Exchange portal](https://stackexchange.com/) logins:

> [image]

---

> [image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I looked around and found out that yes, both the data explorer and stackexchange.com still have a few obsolete openId providers listed in the login / signup options.

I have pushed fixes to both, which will remove claimId (and a couple of others) that are no longer in operation.

The obsolete openId providers will be gone in the next builds of either.

Thanks for reporting.