# Update login icons on Data.SE

Tags: discussion, design, login, data-explorer, openid

When I click login on Stack Overflow, I see this:

[image]

But when I click login on Data SE, I see this:

[image]

This is the old login UI, similar to what [Stack Overflow used to have](https://web.archive.org/web/20140110035153/https://stackoverflow.com/users/login). Now, it is a collection of outdated icons. (The presence of the AOL logo, as well as the shadow-sporting Google logo, show their age.)

Can the UI be updated to match?

Comment: The login is getting changed around a bit anyway for various reasons, so I'll make a note to update the icons while I'm at it.

Comment: [This is already fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243129/152859), waiting for a build. SEDE might take few weeks or months (last build was 6 months ago), but it will be there eventually.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nah, he just updated the provider options, the actual icons for what's left still need updating per this request.

Comment: @Tim oh, didn't know that. Good luck changing the login!